# FrameRenderer avoids the Frame.GestureRecognizers Command on Android

Tags: xamarin.forms

I have created my own button with text and an image. To do so, I used a frame where I encapsulate everything. In Android it should have the button pressed. For that, I used a FrameRenderer, where I have the Touch event in the case of Android and it works great.

The problem is that I also want to use a Frame.GestureRecognizers to send a command when it is pressed, but this apparently cancels the invocation of the event since the command is not executed. It should be noted that I did exactly the same for UWP, and this problem does not happen. I guess I'm eating something on Android. I will share the code with you to see if you can help me. Thank you.

Xaml:

```
            <local:MyFrameButton  
                x:Name="ButtonFrame"
                Grid.Column="0"
                Grid.Row="6"
                Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                Grid.RowSpan="4"
                CornerRadius="5" 
                BackgroundColor="{StaticResource ButtonColor}"
                HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" 
                VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"  
                HeightRequest="172"
                WidthRequest="172"
                Padding="0" >
                <Grid Padding="8">
                    <Label                              
                          Text="{Binding IconCustomer}" 
                          FontFamily="{DynamicResource MaterialFontFamilyID}"                                  
                          FontSize="{OnPlatform Android='45', iOS='45', UWP='55'}"
                          TextColor="White"   
                          HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                          VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" >
                    </Label>
                    <Label 
                          Grid.Row="1"
                          Text="Clientes" 
                          FontSize="17"  
                          TextColor="White"  
                          HorizontalOptions="Center"
                          VerticalOptions="Center" />
                </Grid>
                <Frame.GestureRecognizers>
                    <TapGestureRecognizer 
                            Command="{Binding CustomerListCommand}"
                            />
                </Frame.GestureRecognizers>
            </local:MyFrameButton>
```

ViewModel:

```
  public ICommand CustomerListCommand => new RelayCommand(GoCustomerList);

    private async void GoCustomerList()
    {
        isRunning = true;
        MainViewModel.Instance.CustomersV = new CustomersViewModel(CustomerList);
        await MainViewModel.Instance.CustomersV.LoadConditionInitialsAsync();
        await navigationService.Navigate("CustomersView");
        isRunning = false;
    }
```

FrameRenderer:

```
 class MyFrameButtonRenderer : FrameRenderer
    {

        public MyFrameButtonRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
        {

        }

        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Frame> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if (e.NewElement != null)
            {
                var drawable = new GradientDrawable();
                ViewGroup.SetBackground(drawable);
                UpdateBackgroundColor(drawable);
                UpdateCornerRadius(drawable);
                UpdateOutlineColor(drawable);
                UpdateShadow();

                this.Touch += (v, me) => 
                {
                    switch (me.Event.Action & MotionEventActions.Mask)
                    {
                        case MotionEventActions.Down:
                            Element.Scale = 1.05;
                            break;
                        case MotionEventActions.Up:
                            Element.Scale = 1;
                            break;
                        case MotionEventActions.PointerDown:
                            break;
                        case MotionEventActions.PointerUp:
                            break;
                        case MotionEventActions.Move:
                            break;
                    }
                };
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: Is this frame in a `ListView` or in any `DataTemplate` in general?

Comment: @G.hakim Hello, no, I only had it in a grid. but I could find the solution by changing the FrameRender to the Toch event by public override bool OnTouchEvent (MotionEvent e), this thanks to FaizalSaidali who gave me the advice in Xamarin Forums. https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/376599#Comment_376599

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to change in the FrameRender the Touch event by public override bool OnTouchEvent (MotionEvent e) as I show it below:

```
public override bool OnTouchEvent(MotionEvent e)
        {
            switch (e.Action & MotionEventActions.Mask)
            {
                case MotionEventActions.Down:
                    Element.Scale = 1.05;
                    break;
                case MotionEventActions.Up:
                    Element.Scale = 1;
                    break;
                case MotionEventActions.PointerDown:
                    break;
                case MotionEventActions.PointerUp:
                    break;
                case MotionEventActions.Move:
                    break;
            }
            return base.OnTouchEvent(e);   
        }
```

The idea was given to me by Mr. FaizalSaidali in the Xamarin forum:

https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/376599#Comment_376599